# How does the MITM attack work when a client does not check the hostname vs the certificate?

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, client-side, mqtt

One of the Paho MQTT client SSL options allows checking whether "a certificate matches the given host name.". If I enable this option then I cannot establish a TLS connection to MQTT using an IP address. In case it is relevant: the MQTT client must connect using a client-specific certificate that was generated by the server.

I was curious what vulnerability I'd be opening the client to if I did not enable certificate hostname checking, and I found [RFC 2818, section 3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2818#section-3.1):

> In general, HTTP/TLS requests are generated by dereferencing a URI.
> As a consequence, the hostname for the server is known to the client.
> If the hostname is available, the client MUST check it against the
> server's identity as presented in the server's Certificate message,
> in order to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks.

How does this particular MITM attack work in practice? Would it be possible to diagram or explain an attack scenario and how it plays out step-by-step?

For example, the MITM Wikipedia page walks though the steps of an MITM attack, which was useful in understanding MITM in general: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack#Example

Perhaps the type of MITM I'm asking about is similar to the Wikipedia example, but at least for me it was different enough to prevent me from understanding the role of the hostname check and how it would solve the MITM attack.

EDIT: I feel like my question is similar to the others, but is slightly different due to the use of an IP address to connect issue being tied to not being allowed to do hostname checking. Having it be tied implies that there is some security benefit. But is there? What if the hostname was resolved before the call and the library took the expected hostname in another way. Would that be secure? These are the kinds of questions I was hoping to be able to answer by getting a better understanding of the attack scenario. Where is there room for flexibility, and where isn't there room? I wasn't expecting those specific questions to be answered, but I was hoping to gain the knowledge to answer them myself.

Comment: In short: MITM attacks only work if the client is not properly validating that the server certificate is the expected one. Hostname validation is part of this expectation check. It does not matter much if the client does not check hostname, trust chain, expiration, ... - the basics of the attack are the same and it might only matter how hard it is for the attacker to obtain a certificate trusted by the victim.

Comment: *"I feel like my question is similar to the others, but is slightly different due to the use of an IP address to connect issue being tied to not being allowed to do hostname checking."* - I don't think this is different enough. Hostname checking is about comparing the subject/SAN of the certificate against what you expect it to contain - which can be a domain name but also an IP address. If the IP address is the result of some DNS lookup of a hostname then you should probably compare the certificate to this hostname though and not the IP -- but you cannot simply skip the validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the concept: The whole point of certificates is to bind a public key to some identity, in the case of TLS to a hostname or set of hostnames. If you ignore the hostname when you check a certificate, you have absolutely no idea whose public key it is. In other words, you may establish an encrypted connection, but you don't even know what's on the other end. There's no way to tell if you are in fact communicating with the target server.

An attacker can exploit this as follows:

- First, the attacker needs the ability to intercept and manipulate the network traffic you're sending. They can try that in different locations using different techniques, e. g. by making your PC connect to their Wi-Fi or by taking over a router.
- When you want to make a TLS connection to a server at `target.com`, you must initialize a TLS handshake. The corresponding messages which are exchanged over the network are neither encrypted nor authenticated, so the attacker can intervene whenever and however they want. This means when you receive a certificate as part of the handshake, nothing prevents the attacker from presenting their own certificate which they got for their domain `attacker.com` from a legitimate certificate authority. If you simply accept the certificate regardless of the fact that it has been issued for `attacker.com` rather than `target.com`, then the TLS connection you're about to establish will be between you and the attacker, *not* the target server. All traffic you think you're sending to the target server will actually go the attacker, including passwords or other sensitive data.

To prevent this, you need to verify the certificate, including (but not limited to):

- Has the certificate been signed by a certificate authority which you trust? (In reality, there's going to be chain of certificates which starts with a trusted root certificate and hopefully ends with the certificate at hand.)
- Has it in fact been issued for the hostname of the target server?
- Has it expired?
- Has it been revoked?
- ...

After you've gone through all necessary checks, you can be reasonably sure the public key included in the certificate does in fact belong to the target server. Once you start a key exchange using this public key (which the attacker doesn't know the private key for) and encrypt the traffic, the attacker can no longer read or change the traffic undetected. The best they could do is block it or produce invalid traffic.

Comment: Thank you. Is there an implicit expectation that the DNS lookup to convert the hostname to an IP isn't compromised? Or does that not really matter? Asking another way: why is connecting using an IP address tied to the library not allowing a certificate hostname check? Is it only convenience? For example connecting with a hostname URI means the library already knows the hostname (convenient), otherwise connecting with IP the hostname would have to be told to the library in a different way (slightly clunkier). Or is there more to it?

Comment: To clarify my above comment, I'm basically trying to find out if only allowing the certificate to be checked against the hostname was merely a software implementation decision or was actually a security decision. Because if it's an implementation decision, I could change the library to allow connecting with IP and then still have it perform the hostname check by passing the hostname in another way.

Comment: You can, in principle, establish a TLS connection via an IP address rather than a hostname, but then you need a certificate with this IP address as the subject or as a subject alternative name. Since certificates for IP addresses are somewhat unusual, you may not get them from your current certificate authority, and the library may have trouble handling the certificates, but there's nothing conceptually wrong with a certificate for a public IP address. What I don't quite understand is why you need to use the IP address for the connection. To avoid the costs of buying a domain name?

Comment: It comes down to blocking that happens during DNS lookups in the Paho library when suffering a poor internet connection. After connection the blocking continues periodically as the library is checks whether it's still connected, which involves a DNS lookup each time. That blocking problem is resolved when connecting via IP address. I was hoping it'd be secure to resolve the hostname to IP just before connection, connect via IP, but then also give the Paho library the hostname and have it check the certificate against that hostname. But maybe that wouldn't be secure?

Comment: That would be fine, but a much easier solution is to simply store the IP address for the hostname in the operation system (e. g. `/etc/hosts` on Linux). Then the lookup will work as usual, except it uses the local entry rather than DNS.

Comment: To elaborate on why you don't have to worry about the DNS lookup resulting in the wrong IP address (be it by accident or due to an attack): Once a certificate authority has confirmed that a target server (identified by hostname or IP address) has a particular public key, and you've verified the certificate, you can safely use that public key. If the DNS servers lie to you and give you a wrong IP address for the hostname, then the encrypted traffic is unreadable for that IP address. So in the worst case, you won't reach the target server. DNS attacks are a problem for CAs, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's the basic MitM attack:

1. Attacker creates a certificate he controls
2. Client connect to attacker instead of the server
3. Attacker sends client data to server, and server data to client, logging and changing anything he wants.

As the client does not check the certificate, he cannot know that he is talking to the attacker instead of the server.

Comment: Please elaborate. Apologies, but this isn't telling me anything I didn't already read on the MITM Wikipedia page. I specifically mentioned in my question that the Wikipedia example wasn't enough for me to understand this specific MITM case. Perhaps it's simple and straightforward to you, but not to me yet.

Comment: However, if server requires client authentication with a certificate, as appears to be the case here, MitM cannot fake that upstream (without compromising the client) thus step 3 fails. Most HTTP standards including 2818 were written with web browsing in mind, and _websites_ usually don't require client-auth, but _APIs_ sometimes do.